# Why aren't these commands creating a read-only user in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I've carefully reviewed similar questions on this site and I can't get it to work.

- I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3.9 (installed from package) on Ubuntu 14.04 (Vagrant box).
- I'm creating a new database called `site` owned by `postgres`.
- I want to create a read-only user called `readonly` with access to this database.
- I've tried to lock them out of `SCHEMA public` but whatever I try to do, they can still create tables.

Can anybody help me understand why this user can still write to the database, despite being locked out completely? Here's the steps I'm taking; first, set up the entities and explicitly lock out all the permissions:

```
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE site;
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=# CREATE ROLE readonly UNENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'password' LOGIN NOCREATEROLE NOCREATEDB NOSUPERUSER CONNECTION LIMIT -1;
CREATE ROLE
postgres=# REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA public FROM public;
REVOKE
postgres=# REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA public FROM readonly;
REVOKE
postgres=# REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE site FROM public;
REVOKE
```

Let's check that `readonly` can't connect:

```
vagrant@vagrant-web1:~$ PGHOST=127.0.0.1 PGPASSWORD=password psql -U readonly site
psql: FATAL:  permission denied for database "site"
DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.
```

Everything correct up to this point. Now the superuser grants a single permission:

```
postgres=# GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE site TO readonly;
GRANT
```

This is where the system breaks. The `readonly` user can log in and can create tables:

```
vagrant@vagrant-web1:~$ PGHOST=127.0.0.1 PGPASSWORD=password psql -U readonly site
psql (9.3.9)
SSL connection (cipher: DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256)
Type "help" for help.

site=> CREATE TABLE orders(id int);
CREATE TABLE
site=> \dt
         List of relations
 Schema |  Name  | Type  |  Owner
--------+--------+-------+----------
 public | orders | table | readonly
(1 row)
```

This has had me stuck for a couple of hours. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Extra information:** There's only a single schema in the database. Here's what the output of `\du` is:

```
postgres=# \du
                                                    List of roles
      Role name      |                   Attributes                   |                   Member of
---------------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------
 postgres            | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
 readonly            |                                                | {}
```

Here's the output of \list:

```
postgres=# \list
                                                     List of databases
      Name       |        Owner        | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |              Access privileges
-----------------+---------------------+----------+-------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------
 postgres        | postgres            | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
 site            | postgres            | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | postgres=CTc/postgres                      +
                 |                     |          |             |             | readonly=c/postgres
 template0       | postgres            | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres                                +
                 |                     |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1       | postgres            | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres                                +
                 |                     |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You issued commands `REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA public ...` in database `postgres`, not `site`. Check it:

```
site=> \dn+
                          List of schemas
  Name  |  Owner   |  Access privileges   |      Description       
--------+----------+----------------------+------------------------
 public | postgres | postgres=UC/postgres+| standard public schema
        |          | =UC/postgres         | 
(1 row)
```

Line `=UC/postgres` means that `public` has Usage and Create privileges for schema `public`.

So do the following:

```
site=> \c site postgres
You are now connected to database "site" as user "postgres".
site=# REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA public FROM public;
REVOKE
```

And now it works:

```
site=# \c site readonly
You are now connected to database "site" as user "readonly".
site=> create table t(n numeric);
ERROR:  no schema has been selected to create in
site=> create table public.t(n numeric);
ERROR:  permission denied for schema public
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought the public schema was a global object. Wish I could upvote more than once. Thanks, this has saved me hours of frustration.